Where can I find the a description of the admitted topics?
Unlike other StackExchange sites, I am unable to find a description of the community. 
Where can I find about what I can post and what I cannot post here?

See the FAQ, which every Stack Exchange site has.
Come to think of it, I pointed you to the FAQ the last time I closed one of your off-topic questions.

I read it. As for: What kind of questions should I not ask here? The answer is: Avoid asking questions that have nothing to do with quant.stackexchange.com. Fine, but what are the questions that have nothing to do with quant.stackexchange.com?

@antonio Examples are clearly enumerated: "How do I become a quant?" "What should my thesis topic be?" "Could someone help me develop a trading strategy?"

ah ok, there are 2 FAQs, main and meta FAQ.

The main FAQ is the one I've linked to in this answer as well as in your earlier question. I'm not sure why you are reading the meta FAQ.
